# unable to add sitemap from AWS Amplify

Tags: .htaccess, aws-amplify, sitemap.xml

I'm trying to submit a sitemap to Google that is on AWS Amplify. The sitemap is in XML format and in my site's root folder. When I submit the sitemap in the Google Search Console, I get a 403 forbidden error.

I have a .htaccess file in my site's root folder which may have something to do with the problem. I'm wary of making changes to the .htaccess and mess up the rules I've set up.

This is my htaccess file:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

# deny access to .htaccess
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>

# prevent website directory listing
Options -Indexes

# Disable image hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mattdailey.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.example.com/assets/images/hotlinking.png [R,L]
```

I'm not really sure if I need an .htaccess file on AWS Amplify. I couldn't find anything in the Amplify documentation mentioning .htaccess.

Here is my sitemap XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.example.com</loc>
      <lastmod>2021-02-10</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

How do I get rid of the 403 forbidden error?

Do I modify my .htaccess file or is there a setting in AWS I need to change? I recently moved my site to Amplify and still new to it.

Comment: You ever get this figured out?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Dang, I am stuck as well

Comment: I've also haven't worked on it in quite awhile. I wonder if a sitemap is not needed in an AWS Amplify site.

Comment: Does the sitemap.xml need to even exist in the project at all? Or can i just upload the xml to the Google Search Console?

Comment: I believe it has to be present somewhere on the site.

Comment: Hmm I do think the xml needs to be in the public folder. Isn’t that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably.